# mvc 4 I've deployed to production server. Now cannot connect to localdb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I finally have a published website. Now I want to continue development so I changed my webconfig back to the previous working localdb connection string.

```
    <add name="HouseContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MVCBSV;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVCBSV.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and then commented out the connection string to the production server.

```
<!--<add name="HouseContext" connectionString="Data Source=bstatus2014.db.10188888.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=bstatus2014; User ID=bstatus2014; Password=Bstatus!2014;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
```

But when I run the project, the data that is retrieved is the production data! I've tried clean and then build solution but no effect. Probably related, is that I published to the local IIS following the web deploy suggestions adding an application pool. Also if I use the connection wizard specifying localdb/v11.0 it no longer shows my MVCBSV.mdf db.

Also I was trying to use transforms debug/release to make this change, but have found a post that transforms don't work on debug.

A beginner so explicit answers are a help.

Comment: Make certain that you have eliminated CONFIG transforms as a possible culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, if you publish to your local IIS then your application is probably tied to that site. Open IIS, find the published site open the folder your published code is in and then look at the Web config it is associated to it. Also try recycling the app pool.

Transforms should only be used when you are publishing to a non-local environment anyway. Beyond that if you publish it might make more sense if you published to a location in your file system.

Comment: The plot thickens. I found a post showing how to display your CS:  You are connecting to Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MVCBSV;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVCBSV.mdf)

Comment: The plot thickens. I found a SO post showing how to display your CS:=  You are connecting to Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MVCBSV;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVCBSV.mdf)  This is my local db, however using server explorer, table lot has 4 entries, when the page loads it shows 12 entries. I also just cleared the IE temp files. mystifying